# Problema con la entrada de datos por consola - Dart

Tags: dart, consola

Tengo un problema en este código de Dart. Cuando quiero leer datos por consola me sale un error. Aquí el código:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:aws_dynamodb_api/dynamodb-2012-08-10.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final dynamoDB = DynamoDB(
    region: 'localhost',
    endpointUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
    credentials: AwsClientCredentials(accessKey: 'xywsq', secretKey: 'owac6q')
    );

  print('Ingresa el ID del producto');
  String? id = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: Utf8Codec());
  print('Ingresa el nombre del producto:');
  String? nombreDelProducto = stdin.readLineSync();

  final putItem = dynamoDB.putItem(
    item: {
      'ID' : AttributeValue(n: id),
      'Nombre del producto' : AttributeValue(n: nombreDelProducto),
    }, 
    tableName: 'productos'
  );

  print('Se ingresaron los datos correctamente: $putItem');
}
```

Salida en consola:

```
Unknown evaluation response type: null
#0      DartDebugAdapter.evaluateRequest (package:dds/src/dap/adapters/dart.dart:1076:7)
#1      BaseDebugAdapter.handle (package:dds/src/dap/base_debug_adapter.dart:141:20)
#2      BaseDebugAdapter.handleIncomingRequest (package:dds/src/dap/base_debug_adapter.dart:447:7)
#3      BaseDebugAdapter._handleIncomingMessage (package:dds/src/dap/base_debug_adapter.dart:295:7)
#4      ByteStreamServerChannel._readMessage (package:dds/src/dap/protocol_stream.dart:82:18)
#5      ByteStreamServerChannel.listen.<anonymous closure> (package:dds/src/dap/protocol_stream.dart:53:24)
#6      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
#7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
#8      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
#9      _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
#10     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
#11     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#12     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
#13     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#14     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:185:5)
```

El código trata sobre acciones que se deben hacer en una BD de DynamoDB, sin embargo cuando quiero leer datos por consola aparece ese error. Creo que es que no recibe el dato que se escribe. Agradezco su ayuda.